# Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I am getting error while deploying my app in jboss. 
"

```
JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test-ear.ear\".\"Test-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Test-ear.ear\".\"Test-ejb.jar\".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"Test-ejb.jar\" of deployment \"Test-ear.ear\"
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.XXX.test.inventory.Inventory with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module \"deployment.Test-ear.ear.Test-ejb.jar:main\" from Service Module Loader
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack in method ccom.XXX.test.inventory.Inventory.invokeInventory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;J)Ljava/lang/String; at offset 174"},
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-ear.ear\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"Test-ear.ear\".beanmanager]"]
```

Comment: If you see the logs you see weld.weldClassIntrospector  is complained over. Can you please check. Thanks

Comment: That `java.lang.Verifyerror` indicates that your `Test-Ejb.jar` file is probably corrupt.